# Call the same GraphQL mutation action many times in one http request

Tags: graphql

I am using the GitHub v4 API (GraphQL).
I am wondering if I can somehow send the same mutation action* many times in one http request.

*(with different parameters ofc)

For example, let's say I want to create 3 labels in one http request or update 10 issues in one request.
The relevant API mutations are [createLabel](https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/createlabel/) and [updateIssue](https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/updateissue/).
I can make it work if I only do one mutation per http request. However, I can't find a correct incantation of the syntax that will allow multiple calls of the same mutation in the same http request.
Is it even possible?

Here is a sample query that works for one mutation per request:

```
{
  "query": "mutation CreateLabel1 {
              createLabel(input: {color:\"FF0000\", name:\"TESTING\", repositoryId:\"ID\"}) {
                label {
                  id
                }
              }
            }"
}
```

PS: Assume that I construct the string myself without the help of a 3rd party graphql library.

**EDIT**
Since I have <15 reputation I can't leave an answer to my question.
However, I would like to leave an example with raw syntax for future me/others to better understand it.

Special thanks to @DanielRearden for pointing to the correct place. I knew I had read it somewhere but after fiddling with my code I forgot it.
Read about aliases to the link @DanielRearden posted and [this one](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) too.

Sample syntax:

```
{
  "query": "mutation CreateLabel1 {
              label1: createLabel(input: {color:\"FF0000\", name:\"TESTING1\", repositoryId:\"ID\"}) {
                label {
                  id
                }
              }
              label2: createLabel(input: {color:\"FF0000\", name:\"TESTING2\", repositoryId:\"ID\"}) {
                label {
                  id
                }
              }
            }"
}
```

Here `label1` and `label2` are the aliases and will appear in the response JSON too.

Comment: You would alias each mutation field as shown in the linked post.

Comment: @DanielRearden any chance of raw graqhql syntax? I can't understand the JS (?) example from the linked post.

Comment: Just ignore the JavaScript and look at the query between the backticks. The syntax for an alias is just putting the alias name and a colon before the field name.

Comment: You can also take a gander [here](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Field-Alias).

Comment: @DanielRearden thank you! I posted an edit to my original question.